# Right-aligned tabs have an undesired gap to the side

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some problems:

1. I have a tab-div - you can find the code here: http://pastebin.com/KPpgEBi6. As you can see in this https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2MUn.png where the arrows point, there is some space, the tab doesn't start at the right corner, how can I fix it?
2. There is also some underline that continues behind the content `div`.

What to do?

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container" style="width: 45%;float: right;">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs navbar-right">
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#sub_cats_{CID}">{SUB_CATEGORIES}</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#category_{CID}">{CATEGORY}</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="tab-content" style="height: 100%;">
        <div id="category_{CID}" class="tab-pane fade in active category" style="background-image: url('{CATEGORY_IMAGE}');">
         <h1> {CATEGORY_NAME} </h1>
        </div>
        <div id="sub_cats_{CID}" class="tab-pane fade">
            <ul class="sub_categories">
             <li><a href="products.php?act=scat&id=7">ONE</a></li>
                <li><a href="products.php?act=scat&id=8">TWO</a></li>
                <li><a href="products.php?act=scat&id=12">THREE</a></li>
                <li><a href="products.php?act=scat&id=13">FOUR</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide your html and css codes in jsfiddle as the current pastebin codes you provided is not enough for us to debug the issue

Comment: you need to add class `pull-right`

Comment: dosent work, here is the all page: http://jsfiddle.net/ep2drocb/

Answer (score 1):

You really don't want to be applying inline styles to primary grid elements like that. Work *with* your framework, not against it.

The fix here seems to be to align your tabs right:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs navbar-right pull-right">
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ymt34fjc/)**

Update: The issue is your application of RTL across the site. Reverse it for the nav tabs:

```
.nav-tabs {
  direction: ltr;
}
```

**[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/ep2drocb/6)**

Comment: hey , dosent work, look what i did: http://jsfiddle.net/ep2drocb/ this all my source code. and i dont understand what you say in the start of your message, what i did wrong?

Comment: You're not using Bootstrap's grid correctly. You should almost never apply widths to containers. See an updated version here, where I've used rows and columns: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/ep2drocb/1

Comment: first, tanks, the direction fix the underline and the space, but as you can see in this picture: http://srv1.jpg.co.il/1/55521224c5496.png . the content dosent start at where the tab start, there is some space there, how to fix it?

Comment: Here's a simplified demo. Please add an image to it so we have something to look at. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/ep2drocb/3/

Comment: Here's one with a background image that loads. Does  it show the problem? http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/ep2drocb/4/

Comment: you can see image of the problem in last message, but anyway, i see that you do a demo with a background, as you can see i your demo, the background color dosent start where the tab start at the right side...

Comment: The `navbar-right` class was pulling the tabs outside their container. See the fixed version here: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/ep2drocb/6

Comment: thanks works good, another que, do you have any clue how to do border to the content? i mean like they did here: www.livedns.co.il ,(right site at the middle of the page) as you can see, the active tab dosent have a border at the bottom....

Comment: Please don't ask new questions in comments. Use your browser's inspector to see how it was done there. If you have trouble, start a new question with a *simplified* demo fiddle.